# ALTER TABLE with missing FROM-clause entry for table "inventory"

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

`ALTER TABLE inventory.subtitles
   ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT (inventory.subtitle_subtitle_id_seq);`

produces missing FROM-clause entry for table "inventory"

but even pgadmin 3 gives me the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `SET DEFAULT (inventory.subtitle_subtitle_id_seq)`. Postgres interprets this as "the column `subtitle_subtitle_id_seq` from the table `inventory`" which is clearly not your intention.

First of all, you can't get a value from a sequence with just the bare sequence name like that. Generally, you would use `nextval('sequence_name')`.

You probably want something like:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory.subtitles
    ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('inventory.subtitle_subtitle_id_seq');
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.
interestingly pgadmin III does give a wrong syntax when trying it....